# Instagram Scraper running slow

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, optimization, web-scraping

Can someone help me how to speed up this scraping process getting all the usernames from the # 'dogs' on instagram. My goal is to make this as fast as possible because currently the process is kinda slow. Maybe using multithreading?

```
from instaloader import Instaloader

HASHTAG = 'dogs'

loader = Instaloader(sleep=False)

users = []
for post in loader.get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG):
    if post.owner_username not in users:
        users.append(post.owner_username) 
    print(post.owner_username)
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically? Have you done any benchmarking/profiling?

Answer (score 0):

Use a set instead of a list - it's significantly faster for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove the print statement. That’s the bottleneck. When you print something to the terminal, the terminal needs to slow the process otherwise it would look like it’s spazzing out.
2) Use set instead so you don’t have to check if post.username exist

```
users = set()
for post in loader.get_hashtag_posts(HASHTAG):
    users.add(post.owner_username)
```

Comment: _Remove the print statement. That’s the bottleneck._ Did you profile the program? I would have assumed that if anything, networking would be the bottleneck.

Comment: I agree with AMC. Bottleneck must be networking. As i see Instaloader doesn't using asyncio, so it should be very slow by design.

Comment: @Lawrence Khan thank you very much. I'm kinda new to python and after making you recommended changes, I don't know how to see the output. Do I need to print them on a .txt or .xls file? Would appreciate some help:)

Comment: Yes declare a file pointer like this before your loop.     output = open(“insta_users.txt”,”w”) then in the loop output.write(post.owner_username +”\n”) then after the loop close the file like so output.close()